# Are there weak versions of the axiom of choice equivalent to weak versions of Zorn's lemma and similar principles?

Tags: logic, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I recalled reading about other weaker forms of $AC$, for example countable choice, where we could make choices from a sequence $(S_{k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ of non-empty sets. I also recalled mention of dependent choice, whereby given a relationship $R$ on a set $X$ such that $(\forall x \in X)( \exists y \in X)(x R y)$, one can construct a sequence $(x_{k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \in X^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that $x_{k} R x_{k + 1}$ for all $k$.

My question is, is there much use in defining notions of choice similar to countable choice for larger infinite cardinals? Foe example, if $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal, then is there a use in defining $AC_{\kappa}$ by saying that for any family $(S_{i})_{i \in I}$ of non-empty sets, where $\mathrm{card}(I) \leq \kappa$? Or is there some analogous way to define dependent choice for something "bigger" than sequences? Moreover, I am familiar with a long list of results which are equivalent to $AC$, e.g. the existence of a well-order for every set, Zorn's lemma, Tychonoff's theorem, etc.; for these weaker choices, are there analogous assertions which are equivalent to this weaker choice, e.g. is there some weak form of Zorns's lemma equivalent to $AC_{\kappa}$?

I'm interested in "how much" of the body of results typically associated with choice you can recover from these weaker forms of it. For example, "how much" choice do I need to prove the existence of a unique closure of a field of cardinality $\kappa$? What about to show that for a set $X$ of infinite cardinality $\kappa$, the Kleene closure $X^{*} : = \bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} X^{n}$ of $X$ has cardinality $\kappa$? In other words, $AC$ has a lot of results that say things like, "For every set $X$ with this and that property, you can do this with $X$", or "For any family of non-empty sets $(X_{i})_{i \in I}$ where all $X_{i}$ have some property, then $\prod_{i \in I} X_{i}$ has some property". But suppose I have my infinite set $X$, or my infinite set $I$, and want to make those same statements. Then how little choice could I use and still get away with those statements? For example, if I have a set $I$, and a family $(X_{i})_{i \in I}$ of sets $X_{i}$, where each $X_{i}$ is equitotient with $I$, then what would it take to show that $\bigcup_{i \in I} X_{i}$ is equitotient with $I$ (analogous to the countable union of countable sets being countable)?

Thanks.

Comment: A comment: your professor is wrong (or you misheard) - the reals cannot be countable. What *can* happen is that the reals can be a countable union of countable sets.

Comment: ('m not 100% sold on the new title, but it beats the older one.)

Answer (score 6):

The question is what do you mean by "use". You can show that countable choice does not imply the existence of a non-measurable set; but strengthening it to $\sf DC_{\aleph_1}$ does.

Countable choice is not used at all in the proof that a product of compact *Hausdorff* spaces is compact. This is in fact equivalent to the Ultrafilter Lemma, which is consistent even when countable choice fails spectacularly (in Cohen's first model the Ultrafilter Lemma is true, but there is a subset of $\Bbb R$ which is dense but has no countably infinite subset).

Let me add a quick equivalent for Zorn's lemma. I wrote $\sf DC_{\aleph_1}$ above. Dependent Choice is in fact the restriction of Zorn's lemma in the following way.

> Let $\kappa$ be a well-ordered infinite cardinal. $\sf DC_\kappa$ is [equivalent to] the statement that every partial order $(P,\leq)$ where every chain of order type $\alpha<\kappa$ has an upper bound, has either a maximal element or a chain of order type $\kappa$.

(The original formulation of $\sf DC_\kappa$, due to Azriel Levy, is exactly saying that arbitrary transfinite recursion can be carried up to $\kappa$.)

We can show that $\sf DC_\kappa$ implies $\sf AC_\kappa$, and that every cardinality is comparable with $\kappa$; but neither of those imply $\sf DC_\kappa$ (not even their conjunction! and the implications between these two is a bit intricate). So Dependent Choice principles are really the stronger principles. Most of the time when a laymathematician says "countable choice" what they really mean is $\sf DC_{\aleph_0}$ which is the correct amount of choice to allow recursive definitions.

To your edit let me first point out that if by $\kappa$ you mean an $\aleph$ cardinal, then for the man things you don't need choice at all. If $X$ has cardinality $\kappa$, then by definition it can be well-ordered, and for ordinals we can canonically enumerate the finite sequences and well-order them again, so if $X$ is infinite and well-orderable, $X^*$ is also well-orderable, and they have the same cardinality.

For the specific case of algebraic closures, we can prove there is always an algebraic closure for a well-orderable field; to prove it is unique we can use the Ultrafilter Lemma, which means that there is no reasonable restriction of $\sf AC$ (a la $\sf AC_\kappa$) which is equivalent to it for reasons I wrote above.

Generally, the uses of the axiom of choice are quite ostensible. They might seem similar, and sometimes you can replace one by another, but they end up being very different (again, countable choice vs. ultrafilters). To see what sort of choice you can recover from an assumption, or how much choice is really needed for a proof, you need to work carefully and see what sort of structure you used in a given proof, and what sort of properties and "choice" you've used there.

For example, consider the downwards Lowenheim-Skolem theorem. Given an infinite structure in a countable language, it has a countable elementary submodel. Close investigation of the proof will show that you use dependent choice to produce a sequence of approximations to the submodel, and a careful observation will show that from this theorem you can in fact prove Dependent Choice itself.

But now replace countable by $\leq\kappa$ for some $\aleph$ number, you might expect this to turn up as $\sf DC_\kappa$. The truth, however, is that the recursive constructions are of length $\omega$, so you only use $\sf DC$. But you still need more, and the missing part is exactly $\sf AC_\kappa$. So the downwards L-S theorem for size $\kappa$ is equivalent to the conjunction of $\sf DC+AC_\kappa$. And again, you can prove the other direction and establish an equivalence.

There is no general method, though. There's no general algorithm for solving these sort of problems, and they often end up having clever and less-expected solutions with results that you may not guess in advance.

Let me just finish by pointing out that $\sf ZF$ proves that $\Bbb R$ is *always* uncountable. What it does not prove, which perhaps is what your professor alluded to, is that $\Bbb R$ is *not* the countable union of countable sets (which can, in the absence of choice, be uncountable).

Comment: I really have to go for a bit, but I could add a bit more information later. Just let me know if you have specific points you want me to elaborate.

Comment: When I say "use", I mean that choice can be used to show some pretty cool results. For example, the entirety of Robinson's non-standard analysis is derived from choice (though I understand choice is not necessary). Weak forms of choice can be used to show a number of really cool things, e.g. dependent choice yields Baire's category theorem, Zorn's lemma yields the existence of an algebraic closure for every field, etc. I'm wondering what kind of results you can get out of these weaker forms of choice.

Comment: How can the countable union of countable sets possibly be uncountable? I can see that you use choice to pick the sequence of bijections, but it breaks my brain to think of this result as possibly not being true. Please help me reconcile this! (You logicians and your draw dropping one liners...!)

Comment: @AJY: There are very large books on the topic, and it's an on-going research for the past 50 years. You cannot possibly expect me to write you a complete answer. So you need to be specific. I don't know what you qualify as "cool results", but I feel that my answer was completely off-mark, which says something about your question. I'll be happy to delete this answer or post a new one if I understood your question, and it wasn't "Oh, just cool stuff..." because that's really just a large book.

Comment: @AreaMan: If you need choice to choose the bijections, then without choice you might not be able to choose these bijections. You reconciled it yourself. It's counterintuitive, but everything infinite is counterintuitive, so you shouldn't be very surprised. :-)

Comment: I'm sorry. By "cool", I meant that these are results of significant consequence in their respective fields (e.g. BCT is a pretty significant result). For example, "how much" choice do I need to well-order a set of cardinality $\kappa$? Or what does it take to show that a field of cardinality $\kappa$ has algebraic closure? Perhaps there's some very basic "rule" of what kind of results you can recover for $AC_{\kappa}$ (I don't mean anything particularly formal, but more a sort of "rule of thumb"). Sorry. I hope that makes the question a bit clearer.

Comment: @AJY: Not really clearer; but I'm starting to get that my answer (and my edit to the title) was entirely inappropriate. Perhaps you can cut out the story and just rewrite the question. As for your question, if a set has size $\kappa$, then to well-order it you need exactly nothing of the axiom of choice. Similarly if you have a well-ordered field, to prove it has *an* algebraic closure you need zero choice; to prove it has a unique (up to iso.) you need some choice, but it's open how much choice is that exactly. In any case it's not measured in $\sf AC_\kappa$ since it follows from $\sf BPI$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila - Okay, the sense I'm getting is that my question was just altogether not very interesting.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Can you give an example where it is impossible to construct a bijection without having countable choice? (Which I guess would amount to a countable set of sets with the property that their union being countable implies countable choice?) I am a little more at peace with this result after thinking longer on what it means to be countable ... but it still is weird. (I accept your answer that "everything infinite is counterintuitive.")

Comment: @AJY: I don't know what your question is, I'm sorry. I find a lot of "naive" questions on the axiom of choice are very interesting. I just *really* don't know what you are really asking here. It's too open ended, and you should clarify the main post, not in the comments on my answer (which I may or may not delete in the near future).

Comment: @AreaMan: Give a specific example? When you take an arbitrary sequence of countable sets, for example. In models where the axiom of choice holds, sure it works out fine; in models where it fails it may or may not work out. The failure of choice is spectacularly non-constructive, just as the axiom of choice is. It tells you nothing about where and how this failure looks like, just that it exists. So we can't do much better than that. From "strong failures" we can deduce more, but those are already explicit assumptions about the failure, which you can just say "There is a family such and such".

Comment: @AJY: You asked about Tychonoff's theorem, and I gave an answer; you asked about Zorn's lemma, and I gave an answer. But in the comments here, it became apparent to me that you're asking something else. If my answer covered *some* of what you're interested in, I'd be happy to elaborate to accommodate the rest; but at this point you're letting me guess what the rest is, and I can't make that guess for you.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Okay, thanks. So can I consistently refuse to believe both 1) the axiom of choice holds AND 2) there are countable families of countable sets with uncountable union?

Comment: @AreaMan: The axiom of choice implies that countable union of countable set are countable. So I'll assume that you mean (1) is the failure of choice. And yes, of course, you can assume that "just" countable choice holds, which suffices for proving this; or you can assume that "countable unions of countable sets are countable" which is even weaker than countable choice. But you'll be missing out on some awesomely awesome strange models which make Banach-Tarski almost "reasonable". :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila - Just revised the question. Does that make a bit more sense?

Comment: @AJY: Yes, that makes more sense (except the very first sentence of the post). I need to think whether I want to edit this answer, append to it, or just delete and write a new one. But I'll do it in a little while.

Comment: @AsafKaragila - Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @AJY: I hope that the edit has answered your question better.

Comment: @AsafKaragila - That answered a lot. One last small question: If I have cardinals $\lambda > \kappa$, then are there cases where $AC_{\lambda} \Rightarrow DC_{\kappa}$?

Comment: @AJY: None whatsoever. The only implication is that if for *every* $\aleph$ number $\lambda$, $\sf AC_\lambda$ holds, then $\sf DC_{\aleph_0}$ holds. And you cannot push this proof even one step higher to $\sf DC_{\aleph_1}$. The same can be said about "Every cardinal is comparable with $\lambda$", it does not imply even $\sf DC_{\aleph_0}$ on its own (or with $\sf AC_\lambda$). Here, however, assuming it holds for all $\lambda$ implies full choice so you recover all the $\sf DC$ that you want.

Comment: Fascinating. Thank you.